# C# abstract class, works with array initialization

Tags: c#, oop, design-patterns, abstract-class

As we know that we CANNOT create the instance of `abstract class`.

I just want to know that if we create the array of abstract class, it will sure work.

E.g.

```
public abstract class Creator
{
    public abstract void DoSomething();
}

Creator creator = new Creator(); // this will give you compilation error!

Creator[] creator = new Creator[2]; // this will SURE work and will NOT give you compilation error.
```

Can anybody please let me know that why this is happening and why it is working with array initialization?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The values stored in the array during the initialization will all be `null`, so this doesn't actually create any instance of the abstract class. Array initialization corresponds to the following (correct) line:

```
Creator creator = null;
```

Creating arrays of a type `AbstractClass[]` is actually quite useful, because you can then store references to some concrete (inherited) class in the array. For example:

```
var objects = new object[2];
objects[0] = "Hello";
objects[1] = new System.Random();
```

Then you can for example iterate over the `objects` array and call `ToString()` on all the objects.

Answer (score 3):

The thing to remember here, is you're not creating any instances of `Creator`, you're creating an array of those types, who's value's are `null`.

Answer (score 1):

```
Creator[] creator = new Creator[2];
```

simply initializes an Array to hold two instances of the Creator class. It doesn't actually instantiate any instances of the class for you. Both of those elements will still be `null` until you initialize them.

Answer (score 0):

in C# arrays are different than the base type.
`Creator` and `Creator[]` are two different types.
Only `Creator` is abstract. `Creator[]` is not abstract that's why you can create instances of it.